# Failed to notify project evaluation listener on Android gradle

Tags: android, gradle

I'm trying to add a library to my project via gradle. I'm getting an error:

> Error:Failed to notify project evaluation listener.

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    compileOptions.encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "br.com.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()

    // The library owner indicates me to add the following lines
    maven {
        url 'http://clojars.org/repo'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.8'
    compile 'com.github.machinarius:preferencefragment:0.1.1'
    compile 'com.pavelsikun:material-seekbar-preference:0.8+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.0.+'
    compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.9.0'
    compile files('libs/itextpdf-5.5.6.jar')
    compile 'json-to-pdf:json-to-pdf:0.7.5' // Here is the library that's causing an error
}
```

The project doesn't sync. I don't know how to solve this.

EDIT: Here is my top leve build gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to 

all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your top `build.gradle` look like? Please update all of your plugins.

Comment: I was talking about all of your gradle dependencies.

Comment: I'm sorry. That's all. I'm not sure what file you're asking me to show.

Comment: I am not asking you to show anything. You need to update all of you plugins, then start from there. For instance the latest `com.android.tools.build:gradle` is `1.3.0`. The cardview and recylcerview are `22.2.1`. You said this problem only started **after** you added the last dependency?

Comment: Exactly. If I comment the line compile 'json-to-pdf:json-to-pdf:0.7.5' the problem goes away. I updated my gradle to 1.3.0 and my cardview to 22.2.1 and the same error appears.